# Заменить в строке [block=1] на название функции

Tags: функции, регулярные-выражения, php

Например есть в базе текст:

> Съешь ещё этих мягких [block=1] французских булок.

При выводе `[block=1]` должен заменится на название функции.

```
function block($id) {
    echo 'Ура заработал блок номер `'.$id`;
}
```

Вот что должно получится в итоге:

```
Съешь ещё этих мягких block(1);  французских булок.
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Не совсем понял - должен замениться уже отработанный функцией код - или так как вы написали?

Comment: @Aios должен замениться уже отработанный функцией код, функцию block() я же не просто так выше написал

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$p = "Съешь ещё этих мягких [block=1] французских булок.";
$p = preg_replace_callback('/\\[([a-zA-Z]+)=([0-9]+)\\]/si', 'preg_handler', $p);

function preg_handler($matches)
{
    return $matches[1]($matches[2]);
}

function block($a)
{ 
    return "блок ".$a." заработал"; 
}
```

Результат самый не предсказуемый)

Comment: но функция же выполняться не будет я прав?

Comment: были правы - я исправил

Comment: @Aios спасибо! то что нужно!

Comment: @do4a добавьте проверку на имена функций и проверку аргументов. Не будет лишним.

Comment: @lampa спасибо!

Comment: Можно еще посахарить запись:  

    preg_replace('/\\[([a-zA-Z]+)=([0-9]+)\\]/sie', 'return $1($2)', $p);